# event handler for clicking a link to ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to add a link to delete a row from a mysql database using jquery and ajax. The data is currently displayed in a table. For some reason, the Click event isn't triggering.

Here's my AJAX call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/* load table with page load*/
$("#sort tbody").load("inc/index_table.php");

/* row deletion */
$(".deletelink").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (request) {
        var answer = confirm("Are you SURE you want to delete this?/nThis action is NOT reversible.")
        if (answer){ return(true); }
        else { return(false); }
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: location.href,
        data: "delete="+id,
        error: function() {
            console.log("Theres an error with AJAX deletion");
        },
        success: function(){ //a.td.tr.remove just that row rather than the whole table
            $this.parent().parent().remove();
            console.log("Deleted.");
        }
   });
}); 

});
</script>
```

And the relevant HTML:
this is part of a while loop that prints a table from my database:

`<td><a class="deletelink" id="'.$row["id"].'"><img src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete"></a></td>';`

My code specifies `<a class="deletelink">` but it's not registering with `$(".deletelink").click(function(){ });`

Does anyone see what could be wrong here or have an alternate method to suggest?

Comment: an anchor needs the 'href' attribute to be valid...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are loading the elements dynamically. You can only bind to elements which currently exist in the DOM. To bind to elements which you are about to add, you must attach the event to a static element, the closer it is to the dynamic content, the better.

Try using [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on) with a delegate.

```
$("#sort tbody").load("inc/index_table.php");

/* row deletion */
$("#sort tbody").on("click", ".deletelink", function(){
   //...rest of code the same
});
```

`on()` was added in jQuery 1.7. If you are using a previous version, but higher than 1.4.2 you can use [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

```
$("#sort tbody").load("inc/index_table.php");

$("#sort tbody").delegate(".deletelink", "click", function(){
   //...rest of code the same
});
```

If `#sort` or `tbody` of `$("#sort tbody")` is also dynamic then `$("document").on("click", "#sort tbody .deletelink", function(){...})` would work as well, though anything closer than `document` is better off course.

**Edit**
I'm just looking at your code again, the delegate binding should work, however, using [**load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s success callback should work with your existing code too.

The callback is executed ones load has successfully completed. I'm not 100% certain but I'm assuming that when success is called that the elements already have been loaded into the DOM and as such the normal bindings should work.

If that doesn't work the dynamic bindings mentioned above should.

```
$("#sort tbody").load("inc/index_table.php", function(){
    /* row deletion */
    $(".deletelink").click(function(){
        // .. your code as before.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

to make sure the table is fully loaded, try to declare the click function, in the callback of `.load()` like,

```
      $("#sort tbody").load("inc/index_table.php", function() {

      /* row deletion */
    $(".deletelink").click(function(){ ....
     });
   });
```

Comment: +1 I though about that afterwards as well but wasn't 100% certain if at the time of the callback the DOM has already been updated but I definitely would give that a shot too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **.on()** to bind the events to the elements

```
$(".deletelink").on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
```

Also make sure to add preventDefault to stop the default functioning of the link

Comment: `$(".deletelink").click(function()` calls `.on('click'` anyways.  I think you meant to use the delegated version.

Comment: try the way @François Wahl suggested.. thats the way to go

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your delete link appears after the table loads. So when page was loaded and DOM tree was built, it wasn't there. So you can't attach a `click` to it.
You can try `live()`. This can be used as

```
$(".deletelink").live('click',function(){
    // ajax call handling code here
});
```

This function attaches event after the element has been introduced in the DOM. However, this function is a bit greedy as it keeps on scanning entire DOM tree on any DOM change. So use with caution

Comment: that is deprecated as of 1.7.0

Comment: live() has been deprecated since 1.7 and replaced bwith Delegate  since 1.4 due to its many, many drawbacks. See the live() docs for all the problems is has. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: is it? Great. Gotta keep an eye out